# Flutter how to check Internet connection is available or not

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity/example Issue is its not showing or print internet is connected or not.

This is my code

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  String _connectionStatus = 'Unknown';
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initConnectivity();
    _connectivitySubscription =
        _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (mounted) {
        if (userManager.getCurrentDriver() != null &&
            userManager.getCurrentDriver().isNotEmpty) {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(FIREBASE_PATH_TRIP)
              .doc(userManager.getCurrentDriver())
              .get()
              .then((event) {
            if (event != null) {
              var trip =
                  DriverModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.data()));
              Provider.of<TripState>(context, listen: false).driver = trip;
              Provider.of<BottomSheetSelector>(context, listen: false)
                  .changeSheet(SheetType.Profile);
            } else {
              userManager.saveCurrentDriver('');
            }
          });
        }
        if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
          checkForAndroidUpdate(context);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initConnectivity() async {
    ConnectivityResult result;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) {
      return Future.value(null);
    }

    return _updateConnectionStatus(result);
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _drawerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    ScreenUtil.init(context);

    return SafeArea(
        child: WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _drawerKey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        drawer: ViteDrawer(),
        body: null,
      ),
    ));
  }

  Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
    switch (result) {
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result.toString());
        break;
      default:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = 'Failed to get connectivity.');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

What i need to do is simple print if internet is connected or not. I want to show alert but print is ok so ill manage it. But dont know why its not printing anything

Comment: If your app depends on Internet connection, try call connectivity check in `build` method in `FutureBuilder` widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
  Future<bool> check() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      print("Connected}");
      return true;
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      print("Connected}");
      return true;
    }
    print("not Connected}");
    // return You can add your dialog for notify user to your connectivity is off
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to check the connectivity

```dart
Future<bool> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
  try {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
Future<bool> isConnected() async {
   var result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
   return result != ConnectivityResult.none;
}
```